# Laravel 9 is rejecting a valid password hashed with bcrypt

Tags: php, laravel

I've been spending a few days troubleshooting a failure of certain passwords to validate in Laravel 9. The password `testperson` resolves to the hash `$2y$10$5xc/wAmNCKV.YhpWOfyNoetCj/r3Fs5TyAskgZuIF/LEItWfm7rPW`. A direct query on the corresponding database table confirms that this is the correct hash. Yet Laravel's authentication infrastructure rejects this password and denies authentication.

This is not universal. I have multiple passwords that are resolving correctly. For example, the password `eo` resolves to `$2y$10$uNWYvMVmagIwQ2eXnVKLCOAK1QFQdcRtxbvlghf.Xpg0U1w.N./N2`, and Laravel authenticates that password. The same mechanism creates both of these user records, though they have different permissions (indicated by boolean values on the record).

I tracked down the bug to the function `password_verify`, which was identified as returning false negatives in [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34178309/php-password-verify-returning-false-when-it-should-be-true) and [this Treehouse thread](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/passwordverify-returns-false-for-correct-password).

Specifically, here is the stack in Laravel that gets down to this failure point:

- The `login` route calls `\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers::login` via the controller class.
- The `login` method calls `\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers::attemptLogin`.
- The `attemptLogin` method calls the `attempt` method of the controller's guard object.
- `\Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::attempt` calls `\Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::hasValidCredentials`.
- `\Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::hasValidCredentials` calls the `validateCredentials` method on the guard's provider object.
- `Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider::validateCredentials` calls the `check` method on its hasher object.
- `Illuminate\Hashing\HashManager::check` calls the `check` method on its driver.
- `Illuminate\Hashing\BcryptHasher::check` calls `Illuminate\Hashing\AbstractHasher::check`.
- `Illuminate\Hashing\AbstractHasher::check` calls `password_verify`.

After unwinding this entire stack, I ran the following code in the `login` method of the login controller:

```
$provider = $this->guard()->getProvider();
$credentials =  $this->credentials($request);
$user = $provider->retrieveByCredentials($credentials);
$password_unhashed = $request['password'];
$password_hashed = $user->getAuthPassword();
$password_verify = password_verify($password_unhashed, $password_hashed);
logger('attemping login', compact('password_verify','password_unhashed','password_hashed'));
```

That dumps this context:

```
{
"password_verify": false,
"password_unhashed": "testperson",
"password_hashed": "$2y$10$5xc/wAmNCKV.YhpWOfyNoetCj/r3Fs5TyAskgZuIF/LEItWfm7rPW"
}
```

And if I put that password into a `SELECT users WHERE password=` query, I get the user that I'm expecting.

What's going on here? And how do I get around this?

Comment: It seems to be in the storing, not the retrieving. The hashed password is coming from the database, so the query will always work. When I use your data with password_verify, it returns false. Try re-hashing and saving the password, then see if it works.

Comment: From https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php there's the warning 'The salt option is deprecated. It is now preferred to simply use the salt that is generated by default. As of PHP 8.0.0, an explicitly given salt is ignored.'

Answer (score 0):

I think your assertion that the hash you provided is a hash of 'testperson' is in fact false. Since hashing is one-way, I can't tell you what the hash you showed is derived from. NOTE: This runs on PHP 7.4, but I don't think it will work on PHP 8 and beyond because of the deprecation of the salt option in password_hash().

```
<?php
//$testhash = '$2y$10$5xc/wAmNCKV.YhpWOfyNoetCj/r3Fs5TyAskgZuIF/LEItWfm7rPW';
$testhash = '$2y$10$uNWYvMVmagIwQ2eXnVKLCOAK1QFQdcRtxbvlghf.Xpg0U1w.N./N2';
//$password = "testperson";
$password = "eo";
$options = array("cost" => 10, "salt" => substr($testhash, 7, 22));
$pwhash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options);
echo $pwhash."\n";
$salt = substr($pwhash, 0, 29);
echo $salt."\n";
$cryptpw = crypt($password, $salt);
echo $cryptpw."\n";
if (password_verify($password, $cryptpw)) {
  echo("Verified.\n");
} else  {
  echo("NOT Verified.\n");
}
if (password_needs_rehash($cryptpw, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options)) {
  echo("Needs rehash.\n");
} else {
  echo("Doesn't need rehash.\n");
}

/*
testperson results...
$2y$10$5xc/wAmNCKV.YhpWOfyNoeVNPMEcYrxepQeFAssFoAaIYs4WLmgZO
$2y$10$5xc/wAmNCKV.YhpWOfyNoe
$2y$10$5xc/wAmNCKV.YhpWOfyNoeVNPMEcYrxepQeFAssFoAaIYs4WLmgZO
Verified.
Doesn't need rehash.

eo results...
$2y$10$uNWYvMVmagIwQ2eXnVKLCOAK1QFQdcRtxbvlghf.Xpg0U1w.N./N2
$2y$10$uNWYvMVmagIwQ2eXnVKLCO
$2y$10$uNWYvMVmagIwQ2eXnVKLCOAK1QFQdcRtxbvlghf.Xpg0U1w.N./N2
Verified.
Doesn't need rehash.
*/
?>
```

Comment: The hashes are the correct ones. A direct query of `SELECT users WHERE password="<hash>"` returns the expected user.

Comment: What I'm saying is your password 'testperson' does not go with the hash mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I have a call to `Hash::make` in the observer for the user class. I discovered that it was running even though it wasn't supposed to, resulting in a duplicate hash.

Comment: The observers will *always* run, unless you specifically disable them.